# Volatillity missing MODULE LICENSE()

Tags: volatility

I'm trying to make a profile in Volatility 2. I tried on Debian, Kali and Ubuntu 120.04 and Ubuntu 18 (gcc 7.5.0). I tried to update the headers, export pathes etc.. but still I have the same error . I tried also to dowload a profile from github but they are too old ( i didn't found nothing new - just Ubuntu 14) . I also checked module.h info but didn't find antything helpfull.  Any idea what i can do?

```
make -C //lib/modules/4.15.0-162-generic/build CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO=y M="/root/volatility-master/tools/linux" modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-162-generic'
  CC [M]  /root/volatility-master/tools/linux/module.o
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
WARNING: modpost: missing MODULE_LICENSE() in /root/volatility-master/tools/linux/module.o
see include/linux/module.h for more information
  CC      /root/volatility-master/tools/linux/module.mod.o
  LD [M]  /root/volatility-master/tools/linux/module.ko
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-162-generic'
dwarfdump -di module.ko > module.dwarf
make -C //lib/modules/4.15.0-162-generic/build M="/root/volatility-master/tools/linux" clean
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-162-generic'
  CLEAN   /root/volatility-master/tools/linux/.tmp_versions
  CLEAN   /root/volatility-master/tools/linux/Module.symvers
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-162-generic'
```